# Calculating distance between two squares of a board

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, metric-spaces

Given an $n\times n$ board, for example a chess board 8x8, with  the squares   ordered in a   [Little-Endian Rank-File Mapping](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Square+Mapping+Considerations). Is there a direct way to calculate the distance between two squares using their  numbers (coordinates) on the board?

Comment: This may be a computer science question.  Can you be more specific about the question, and show what work you've done?  What do you mean by distance?

Comment: @DrXorile i'm not asking for a way to program this ,the simplest way would be to pre-store the result in an array,i'm asking if there is an equation to calculate the distance based on the numbers of the 2 squares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a few wild guesses as to what you mean.  Suppose the board squares are numbered 0 to 63 in a rastering kind of way.  And that the distance you're referring to is the smallest number of horizontal and vertical steps you would need to take to get from one square to the other.

Then the vertical distance between $a$ and $b$ is simply:
$|\lfloor{\frac{a}{8}}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{b}{8}\rfloor|$

The horizontal distance is simply: $|(a\mod 8)-(b\mod 8)|$

So the total distance is:
$|\lfloor\frac{a}{8}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{b}{8}\rfloor|+|(a\mod 8)-(b\mod 8)|$

You can see it here:
[Wolfram alpha distance calculation - set a and b](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%3D51%2Cb%3D28%2Cabs%28floor%28a%2F8%29-floor%28b%2F8%29%29%2Babs%28%28a%258%29-%28b%258%29%29)

Comment: thank you , does this takes into consideration the diagonal distance ?

Comment: No it does not.  I just guessed what you meant by distance.  It would not be too hard to modify.  It would simply be the maximum of the horizontal and vertical distances mentioned above, rather than the sum.